# finding corresponding eigen vector to eigen value for linear system

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question where I am trying to find the general solution of a linearised system, which I have linearised. I am just having difficulty obtaining the correct corresponding eigenvectors to my eigenvalues. I am usually fine at these but I am not getting the correct answer (I have solutions). I will highlight my issue below.

My matrix A for my linearised system is given by

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and my eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2=-1$ which I have found with no problem

However, I then know eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are found as follows, again usually fine with:

$(A-\lambda_1 I)v_1=0$ and $(A-\lambda_2 I)v_2=0$

i.e $(A-\lambda_1 I)v_1= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$v_1=0$

So, we have $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  v_1 \\
  v_2 \end{array} \right)=0$

So $0v_1+0v_2=0$
and $-1v_1+1v_2=0$

i.e $-1v_1=-1v_2 \implies v_1=v_2=1$ so corresponding eigenvector to eigenvalue $\lambda_2=-1$ is $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  1 \\
  1 \end{array} \right)=0$

This is all fine. Here is where I am stuck. Now to find the corresponding eigenvector to eigenvalue $\lambda_2=0$

We want to find $v_2$ such that  $(A-\lambda_1 I)v_2= Av_2= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$v_2=0$

So this is where I am stuck:

trying to find eigenvector $v_2$ we have $-1v_1+0v_2=0$
and $-1v_1+0v_2=0$

The solution says $v_2=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  0 \\
  1 \end{array} \right)$
However I cannot see how the writer has got this. Please forgive my stupidity but obviously if $-1v_1+0v_2=0$ then $v_1=0$ but how do they find $v_2$? the fact that both $v_2$ coefficients are zero is confusing me, any help much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Note: $\lambda_2=-1$

Comment: typo at beginning - fixed now - answer still same though

Comment: You are confused because you are using $v_2$ for a vector as well as for a scalar at the same time!

Comment: i know i dont know why he has done that - but no I am confused as to how to work out, say $c_2$ instead if this is the case, i.e $-1c_1+c_2=0$ and $-1c_1+c_2=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have confusing notation, as you use $v_2$ for both the vector and the component of the vector.

---

That said, in my answer, $v$ is a vector with components $v_1$ and $v_2$

You have a system of equations, the first $$-v_1= 0$$

and the second $$-v_1 =0$$

Now, any pair $v_1, v_2$ which satisfies both equations is an eigenvector. Clearly, $v_1$ must be $0$, and clearly, if $v_1=0$, the pair will satisfy the system for *ANY* value $v_2$. Therefore,

$$(A-0\cdot I) v = 0$$

if and only if $v$ is a multiple of $(0,1)$.

Comment: Why $(0,1)$? Im just confused about the $1$ to be honest, because when I look at it, it could also be 0 surely?

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews It can be anything, $(0,2)$ is also an eigenvector. Just like for $\lambda_1$,  where $(2,2)$ is also an eigenvector.

Comment: hang on just read again, so it could  be any $v_2$? This is what and I thought and hence confused as to how to pick. So how do I know v must be a multiple of $(0,1)$? Sorry for my confusion, I am feeling a bit stupid and rushed for an exam..

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews Yes, it can also be $0$, but remember that for a matrix $A$, $x$ is an eigenvecor if $x\neq 0$ and $Ax=\lambda x$. Therefore, you must find a *NONZERO* vector.

Comment: Ahh, okay, hand on it doesnt matter does it? Can be (0,b) where b is any positive integer?

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews For any $v_2$, the vector $(0,v_2)$ is a multiple of $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews No, not just a positive integer. $(0,-0.89498345703984)$ is also an eigenvector.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I think I am seeing it clearly now.. That fact it could be anything was confusing me, but i think I see what you are saying, it must be a mulitple of (0,1), hence what I said? Thanks a lot, sorry I appreciate how stupid this probably is..

Comment: ahh okay! It really can be anything then, because of the zero

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews The way I understand it is that really, matrices don't have eigenvectors, they have eigen*spaces*. For each eigenvalue $\lambda$, the matrix $A$ has an eigenspace which is equal to all vectors for which $Ax=\lambda x$. This space is the nullspace of $Ax - \lambda x$, and it may have more than one dimension. In your particular case, the nullspace is one-dimensional, and the basis vector of the nullspace is $(0,1)$. So, in a way, when you say "the eigenvector is $(0,1)$", you are saying "the basis of the nullspace is $\{(0,1)\}$"

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews And no, it's not stupid. It's a very important concept and it's vital that you fully grasp it.

Comment: Thanks very much! Yes that is why i asked such a "stupid" question, I really want to grasp it properly, actually further on in my course null spaces are introduced. I am taking a dynamical systems course and have realised I didn't grasp it as well as I had thought and now my exam is approaching. Well, that's one thing cleared up! Many thanks.

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews You know, if the answer is what you needed, you can also accept it ;)

Comment: I do yes, I have just come back to accept it and ask another DS question :) I come on a lot :) I voted your comments up too :)